# User Flows for different user types in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have three distinct types of users for my site, with minimally different claims for them. Looking to use 'standard' user flows for each type, with API connectors for each type performing some background tasks. I want to avoid custom policies, and I want each type to go to their own link (think "`<UserTypes>` register here") mainly for signup/signin purposes and probably edit profile. Password reset should/(could?) be universal/shared.

Using the 'new' AADB2C libraries (namely `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI`) it appears that trying to set up this kind of scenario is vastly more difficult than it once used to be; what makes it worse is that trying to find a scenario to accommodate this is very difficult.

The closest thing I can find to changing the user flow for my user type is the custom controller example in the [Add the Account Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#account-controller) customization option. When I try to change the policy (as opposed to the 'generic default' I put in my `AzureAdB2C` config settings, it throws an error saying it expected the original setting. I get a lot of `AADB2C90088` errors trying to change the value with the technique they mention.

Anyone familiar with setting this up? I can't find the old examples of this anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is a bit of work. It starts with the foreknowledge that user flows are effectively policies - once you grasp that, the rest of it starts to fall into place.

It starts with adding a couple of objects to the solution that were lifted from the [Woodgrove Groceries B2C demo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/woodgrove-groceries-demo):

- `PolicyManager` - an object that simply stores policy (user flow) names for each user type we have (sign up, sign in, profile edit)
- `PolicyConfigurationManager` - a more sophisticated configuration manager for `OpenIdConnectConfiguration` instances. We're going to create one of these per user role, though most of it's going to be the same settings (since we're using the same directory)

In `Program.cs`:

```
void ConfigureAuth()
{
    var authBuilder = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
        
    builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
        // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite
        options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
    });

    var policyManager = new PolicyManager();
    configureOwnerAuthentication(builder.Configuration,authBuilder,policyManager);

}

void configureOwnerAuthentication(IConfiguration configuration, AuthenticationBuilder authenticationBuilder, PolicyManager manager)
{
    var b2cfg = B2CConfig.Construct(configuration);
    var policyList = manager.OwnerPolicies;
    authenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(Constants.AuthenticationSchemes.OwnerAuth, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = b2cfg.Authority;
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/owner-signin-callback");
        options.ClientId = b2cfg.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = b2cfg.ClientSecret;
        options.CorrelationCookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(3);
        options.Events = CreateOwnerConnectEvents(configuration,manager);
        options.ConfigurationManager = new PolicyConfigurationManager(
            b2cfg.Authority,
            policyList);
        options.Validate();
    });
}
```

Note that there's an additional method `CreateOwnerConnectEvents` that essentially wires an `OnTokenValidated` event that lets us connect to some injected services and add additional claims. I'm going to go ahead and post the pseudocode for that, since anyone trying to manage users with Azure AD B2C is probably curious on how to get Roles working without it being a massive headache.

```
OpenIdConnectEvents CreateOwnerConnectEvents(IConfiguration configuration, PolicyManager policyManager)
{
    GraphUtilConfig guc = GraphUtilConfig.Construct(configuration);
    return new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            // do NOT do something like context.HandleResponse() here or the token won't get validated! 
            // Lesson learned there.
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var userRepo = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(UserRepo)) as UserRepo;
            var lookupRepo = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(UserLookupRepo)) as UserLookupRepo;

            var oid = context.Principal!.ObjectId() ?? "";

            if (userRepo == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(oid))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("repos were not extracted from context. exiting OnTokenValidated event");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var groups = userRepo.GetMemberGroupListAsync(oid).Result;
            if (groups.Count == 0) return Task.CompletedTask;


            bool isCustomer = false;
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity
            {
                Label = "MyCustom.Identity"
            };
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(id.NameClaimType,"Application Identity"));
            foreach (var grp in groups)
            {
                if (grp.DisplayName == Constants.GROUPS_CUSTOMERS) isCustomer = true;
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,grp.DisplayName));
            }

            if (!isCustomer)
            {
                var ul = lookupRepo.LookupUserByUserId(oid);
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.BusinessId,ul.BusinessId ?? ""));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.BusinessPath,ul.BusinessPath ?? ""));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.BarberHandle, ul.Handle ?? ""));
            }
            context.Principal!.AddIdentity(id);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}
```

We're using a custom graph library for B2C we call [EPS.Extensions.B2CGraphUtil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPS.Extensions.B2CGraphUtil/) that's specifically created for quickly getting set up to access users and groups in a B2C directory. We take those and store them in the Roles claims for a new identity we'll attach to the user, with a couple of additional business properties we need specifically for our application that come from elsewhere.

Finally, we need our own `AccountController`:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignInOwner()
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        log.LogInformation("owner sign in");
        return LogInFor(Constants.AuthenticationSchemes.OwnerAuth, Constants.UserFlows.OwnerSignIn, "en");
        //return SignIn(Constants.UserFlows.OwnerSignIn,Url.Content("~/"));
    }

    private IActionResult LogInFor(string authenticationScheme, string policy, string uiLocale, bool isSignUp = false)
    {
        
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToHome();
        var authProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {Constants.AuthenticationProperties.Policy, policy}, {Constants.AuthenticationProperties.UILocales, uiLocale}
        };

        return new ChallengeResult(
            authenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>(authProperties)!)
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("LoggedIn", "BSAccount", null, Request.Scheme)
            });

    }
```

Now we're just making sure we use the right scheme and configuration for our Challenge methods. It's important to point out that this is covered in the Azure documentation [Enable authentication options in a web app by using Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options) but quite poorly because they don't really let on about all of the other things that absolutely **have** to be in place first. Very frustrating!